# Xamrin android any file uploading using web services in c#

Tags: xamarin.android

Is that possible to upload any file(doc,pdf,img) in xamarin android using web service in c#. i am using sql server for data connection.

Answer (score 0):

Use MediaFile from the [Xamarin.Plugins.Media](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Media) Library.

```
public static void upload(MediaFile mediaFile)
{
        try
        {
            StreamContent scontent = new StreamContent(mediaFile.GetStream());
            scontent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                FileName = "newimage",
                Name = "image"
            };
            scontent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var multi = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            multi.Add(scontent);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.API_ROOT_URL);
            var result = client.PostAsync("api/photo", multi).Result;
            Debug.WriteLine(result.ReasonPhrase);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
        }
 }
```

And node.js code to receive request.

```
var formidable = require('formidable');
var util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        console.log(file.fieldname);
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('image');

exports.post = function (req, res) {       
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        console.log(req.file);
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR : "+err);
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        console.log("SUCCESS");
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
};
```

See complete information from below thread

- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18649/best-practice-to-upload-image-selected-to-a-web-api
- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5033/upload-file-from-device-to-server

Comment: Thank you for your reply......But this is only for image uploading or any file uploading like pdf,doc,img etc??